# Reference the same linked template in different parent templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I want to deploy resources for storage account, service bus, azure function and web app using ARM templates. Also I want to write storage and service bus connections strings to both function and web app application settings.
So I created a main template which references 2 child templates: one for function and one for web app. Both child templates reference same linked templates for service bus and storage account. 
My composite template is validated successfully but when I'm trying to deploy I've got errors like this:

> Unable to edit or replace deployment `serviceBus`: previous deployment
>   from [datetime] is still active

It seems like Azure tries to deploy service bus and storage account twice. How can I tell ARM to use the same `serviceBus` deployment for both web app and function?

Current simplified schema:

```
      Main ARM template(azuredeploy.json)
     /                                 \
Web App(nestedtemplates/webApp.json)   Function App(nestedtemplates/functions/resourceAllocationFunction.json)
      \                               /
    Service Bus(nestedtemplates/serviceBus.json)
```

### Templates:

### azuredeploy.json

```
"resources": [    
    {
      "name": "webApp",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('webAppTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('webAppTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "mainStorageAccountType": { "value": "[parameters('mainStorageAccountType')]" }, 

          "location": { "value": "[parameters('location')]" },

          "_artifactsLocation": { "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocation')]" },
          "_artifactsLocationSasToken": { "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]" }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "resourceAllocationFunction",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('resourceAllocationFunctionTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('resourceAllocationFunctionTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "mainStorageAccountType": { "value": "[parameters('mainStorageAccountType')]" },    


          "location": { "value": "[parameters('location')]" },

          "_artifactsLocation": { "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocation')]" },
          "_artifactsLocationSasToken": { "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]" }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

### nestedtemplates/webApp.json

```
"resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('servicePlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('servicePlanSkuName')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [],     
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('servicePlanName')]",
        "numberOfWorkers": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('servicePlanName'))]"
      ],      
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('servicePlanName'))]"        
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webAppName'))]",
            "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('appInsightsName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {

            "ServiceBus:ConnectionString": "[reference('serviceBus').outputs.connectionString.value]",
            "ServiceBus:QueueName": "[reference('serviceBus').outputs.queueName.value]",

            "StorageAccounts:WritableAccountName": "[reference('mainStorage').outputs.storageAccountName.value]",
            "StorageAccounts:ConnectionString": "[reference('mainStorage').outputs.storageAccountConnString.value]",           
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "serviceBus",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [ ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('serviceBusTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('serviceBusTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },       
        "parameters": {
          "location": { "value": "[parameters('location')]" }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "mainStorage",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [ ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('mainStorageTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('mainStorageTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },       
        "parameters": {
          "location": { "value": "[parameters('location')]" },
          "mainStorageAccountType": { "value": "[parameters('mainStorageAccountType')]" }
        }
      }
    }
]
```

### nestedtemplates/functions/resourceAllocationFunction.json

```
"resources": [
    {
      "name": "functionStorageAccount",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('functionStorageAccountTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('functionStorageAccountTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "location": { "value": "[parameters('location')]" }
        }       
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "consumptionPlan",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('consumptionPlanTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('consumptionPlanTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "location": { "value": "[parameters('location')]" }
        }       
      }
    },    
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('appInsightsName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[reference('consumptionPlan').outputs.resourceID.value]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
              "value": "[reference('functionStorageAccount').outputs.storageAccountConnString.value]"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[reference('functionStorageAccount').outputs.storageAccountConnString.value]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[reference('functionStorageAccount').outputs.storageAccountConnString.value]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[toLower(variables('functionAppName'))]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
              "value": "dotnet"
            },
            {
              "name": "AccoutLogin",
              "value": "[reference('mainStorage').outputs.storageAccountName.value]"
            },
            {
              "name": "AccountConnString",
              "value": "[reference('mainStorage').outputs.storageAccountConnString.value]"
            },                      
            {
              "name": "ServiceBusConnectionString",
              "value": "[reference('serviceBus').outputs.connectionString.value]"
            },
            {
              "name": "QueueName",
              "value": "[reference('serviceBus').outputs.queueName.value]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "serviceBus",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('serviceBusTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('serviceBusTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "location": { "value": "[parameters('location')]" }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "mainStorage",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('mainStorageTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('mainStorageTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },       
        "parameters": {
          "location": { "value": "[parameters('location')]" },
          "mainStorageAccountType": { "value": "[parameters('mainStorageAccountType')]" }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

### nestedtemplates/mainStorage.json

```
"resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('mainStorageAccountName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('mainStorageAccountType')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [],
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[concat('default/', variables('containerName'))]",
          "type": "blobServices/containers",
          "apiVersion": "2018-03-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('mainStorageAccountName')]"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "resourceID": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('mainStorageAccountName'))]"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('mainStorageAccountName')]"
    },
    "storageAccountContainer": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('containerName')]"
    },
    "storageAccountConnString": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('mainStorageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('mainStorageAccountName')),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
    }
  }
```

### nestedtemplates/serviceBus.json

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
      "name": "[variables('serviceBusNamespaceName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard"
      },
      "properties": {},
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
          "name": "[parameters('serviceBusQueueName1')]",
          "type": "Queues",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', variables('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "lockDuration": "PT5M",
            "maxSizeInMegabytes": "1024",
            "requiresDuplicateDetection": "false",
            "requiresSession": "false",
            "defaultMessageTimeToLive": "P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S",
            "deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration": "false",
            "duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow": "PT10M",
            "maxDeliveryCount": "10",
            "autoDeleteOnIdle": "P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S",
            "enablePartitioning": "false",
            "enableExpress": "false"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "resourceID": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', variables('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]"
    },
    "connectionString": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listkeys(variables('authRuleResourceId'), '2017-04-01').primaryConnectionString]"
    },
    "sharedAccessPolicyPrimaryKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listkeys(variables('authRuleResourceId'), '2017-04-01').primaryKey]"
    },
    "queueName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('serviceBusQueueName1')]"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, this makes very little sense. why do you deploy same thing two times if you only need it one time? answer is - you dont deploy it two times. so move it as a separate resource\separate template and deploy only one. just get its keys into web app\function app.

1. move these deployment to the main template: `mainStorage` and `serviceBus`. remove outputs from them, outputs are not secure.
2. replace `"[reference('mainStorage').outputs.storageAccountConnString.value]"` with appropriate value from the outputs: `"[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('mainStorageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('mainStorageAccountName')),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"`. repeat for all outputs.
3. you also need dependsOn on the webapp\function app to wait until service bus\storage are actually created

ps. makes no sense to create a nested deployment for 1 resource. I'd rework your template into a flat template. it makes no sense to use nested deployment here.

Comment: I don't want to deploy the same thing twice. I just want to reference the same deployment in both child arm templates for web app and function. And I definitely don't want to manually copy keys into all app settings(actually I have a bunch of azure functions)

Comment: so do that, i dont see a problem. if you are asking how to do that, provide your code

Comment: I've updated a question with simplified code. Could tell me how to link templates properly in order to avoid duplicated deployments, please?

Comment: I don't want to use a flat template because I showed you a simplified version. There are also a sql server+database(connection string also should be written to web app and all functions) and bunch of functions(all should share the same app service plan and dedicated storage account). And there are also app insights for each function and web app(Instrumental key also must be written to app settings). So how in this case I can use values from the main template in child templates? As far as I know it's not possible to depend on referenced resources.

Comment: half of what you've written here makes no sense to me, unfortunately. its like you are mixing apples and oranges. you dont need nested templates to deploy shared resources. even if you want to do it that way, you dont need to deploy it twice (why do you deploy it twice? i bet you cant answer this question). move them to the parent template and use listkeys\concat\whatever functions you are already using to pull keys\values from existing resources. alternatively you can continue using reference function to get outsputs, but thats not secure

Comment: I don't deploy it twice. I'm deploying only azuredeploy.json template.

Comment: you trolling or? I see `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` 2 times in each nested template

Comment: I thought that ARM will be able to determine that both `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` point to actually the same thing and will do only one deployment but obviously that's not the case.

Comment: no, you need to move that to a parent template. there is no way it would know those are a same thing (even if they would be, why define something twice for no reason?)

Comment: Ok, I'll move common things(service bus, storage, DB) to the parent template. But how can I reference them in child templates(web app and functions) without `Microsoft.Resources/deployments`? Also how to guarantee that common things are already deployed before child templates deployemnt?

Comment: thats like 10 question under the same question. use dependsOn function to depend on those. dont reference them its not secure. construct key like you do but in the webapp\function template

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you for your help.